# How to assign a user defined variable with environment variable with jenkin pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I need to assign the `BUILD_NUMBER` environment variable to user defined variable.
I tried various options like def, environment block and did not work.
I want to assign variable like `def a = ${BUILD_NUMBER}` and  your input to work this code part will be highly appreciated

```
pipeline{
    agent any   
    environment {
    jenkinbuild=echoRestartedInfo()
    }
    

    stages {    
        
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                echo "stage 1"
                echo "${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                echoRestartedInfo()
                echo "${jenkinbuild}"
            }
        }
    }
}



def echoRestartedInfo() {
    def a = ${BUILD_NUMBER}
    
    return a
      
}
```

The output - `echo "${jenkinbuild}"`
is expected same as `echo "${BUILD_NUMBER}"` but this shows multiple compilation error .

I do not want to code this with script{} as it should be added to each stage

Answer (score 1):

Check the following.

```
def echoRestartedInfo() { 
    return env.BUILD_NUMBER
}
```

Or

```
def echoRestartedInfo() { 
    return "${BUILD_NUMBER}"
}
```

---

I just tried to optimize your function. You can simply replace the return with an assignment if you want to assign to a variable.

```
def a = env.BUILD_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks for the update but I am particular about assign this to a variable  like def a= env.BUILD_NUMBER or  def a= "${BUILD_NUMBER}"

Comment: Thanks it worked. I did a mistake with assigment. def a = env.BUILD_NUMBER works